# I want to check validate birthday Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, validation

```
<b-form-group label="Birthday : " label-for="birthday">
  <b-form-datepicker
    id="birthday"
    :date-format-options="{
      day: 'numeric',
      month: 'numeric',
      year: 'numeric'
    }"
    locale="en"
    v-model="form.birthday"
  ></b-form-datepicker>
</b-form-group>
```

I will create form but I dont know how to convert date to age and check validate too

Comment: watch `form.birthday`, calculate age and warn if the validation fails

Comment: Use `vee-validate` to validate forms in Vue, it's really good, for this, you can write your own rule with vee-validate. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vee-validate